# How to create a new file everytime a method is called?

Tags: java, file

In the code below I tried to set a method which should create files in a directory.

There are two different methods which I tried, but the files seems not to be created.

Perhaps there are some syntax problem?

```
public void makeNewFiles() {
  Date d = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy");
  String ns = sdf.format(d);
  File ntf = File.createTempFile(ns, ".png", directory);
}

public void makeNewFiles() {
  Date d = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy");
  String ns = sdf.format(d);
  File n1 = new File(directory, pathToActualFile);
  File n2;

 if(n1.exists()) {
   n2 = new File(directory, ns + ".png");
   n2.createNewFile();
 }  
}
```

Comment: The parent directory has to exist, but then it should work. Maybe `:` are not allowed in file names, though.

Comment: Are you able to run the program, because that's not proper Java code.

Comment: change public void makeNewFiles to public void makeNewFiles()

Comment: Which operating system are you using? You can't have colons in filenames on Windows. (Also, I suspect you want `HH` rather than `hh`...)

Comment: Assuming there is some typo in the question and methods actually compile, you should remove `:` from the file name if you are on windows, as they are reserved characters used for drives letters.

Comment: I tried to print out the date, it seems okay, without exception or error. It's running on Win7pro(netbeans)and the directory exists, it is paste from JfileChooser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your OS,

```
"hh:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy"
```

might or might not be a **valid** filename (I would simply avoid that **space** resp. the **:** colons in there; that could give you trouble in many environments). To be precise: most modern OSes accept spaces in file names, but especially any Unix like file system requires special thought when making command line calls that have to deal with "spacy" filenames. Whereas the colon **:** is more of a no-go; at least for Windows and Unix like OSes.

Then: if your code is called multiple times during the same second; your file name are still "not good enough" to guarantee that you don't re-create the same file again.

Finally: consider adding some kind of "header" to your string; like

```
ns = "whatever-" + sdf.format("hh_mm_ss_dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the space being an issue on some environments? That's completely new for me, I thought space was just fine in filenames!

Comment: @BackSlash: Even if the file system can handle it, people will totally end up writing shell scripts that do `rm -rf $FILEPATH` and that will do funny things.

Comment: @Thilo, GhostCat, Thanks! I got the point, but my opinion is that this way the developer is an issue, rather than the filename: a developer should know filename specifications and should write code that meets the standard (so it should deal with spaces). If he doesn't, he is the issue, not the filename :) But I got the point, it's definitely a way to help inexperienced developers to avoid unnecessary trouble.